# Is there a way I can export a cavity map as a texture so it will appear in other programs after I export?

Tags: shaders

I made this rock and it looks a lot better with the cavity shading enabled. Is there a way I could somehow generate this effect on a PNG texture so I could apply it in another program?

Before:
[image: Before]
After:
[image: After]

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question lmao

Comment: You will likely have to UV unwrap your object onto a texture (an empty image) and the *bake* the colors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but every time I try to bake it it keeps on erroring saying "no image in material (0) found" even though I unwrapped the texture. (Sorry, I'm obviously pretty new to Blender)

Comment: No problem, being new to Blender is part of the process. My comment was merely an indication of the right keyword. I'd suggest following a tutorial on baking and apply it to your question after having understood the subject. In Blender you will bake onto the image in the selected image node of the material. Before baking, add an image node in the node graph of the material of the object, load the image into it and select it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but thank you so much!